# python selenium cannot find the right object. How to determine the right frame?

Tags: python, selenium

I do a very short recording with Selenium IDE this is the IDE generate code:

```
import pytest
import time
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

class TestProv():
  def setup_method(self, method):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.vars = {}
  
  def teardown_method(self, method):
    self.driver.quit()
  
  def test_prov(self):
    self.driver.get("https://portal.ppp.us/hrj/pstrtal")
    self.driver.set_window_size(1144, 699)
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "def").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "def").send_keys("Usr")
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "logonpassfield").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "logonpassfield").send_keys("Pwd")
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "button").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Løn- og Personaleoplysninger").click()
    element = self.driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Løn- og Personaleoplysninger")
    actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
    element = self.driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Løn- og Personaleoplysninger")
    actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
    element = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body")
    actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element, 0, 0).perform()
    self.driver.switch_to.frame(3)
    self.driver.switch_to.frame(2)
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "htmlb_417198_htmlb_144219_1").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "htmlb_417198_htmlb_144219_1").send_keys("03-07-2020")
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "htmlb_417198_htmlb_144219_7").click()
```

The problem I have is in the last 5 lines. the ID htmlb_417198_htmlb_144219_1 changes for every time the numbers are different however the structure is the same so I search the object with:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[substring(@id, 1, 6) = 'htmlb_' and substring(@id, string-length(@id) - 1) = '_1']")
```

which finds objects with the above structure.

However it finds among many others the field:

```
htmlb_417198_htmlb_1442**21**_1
```

while the IDE recorder registered a slightly different ID (we speak of the same session):

```
htmlb_417198_htmlb_1442**19**_1
```

I simply cannot find the field I am looking for (which I clearly can see with an inspect with the correct ID). So I am not catching the right object with my statement, it seems like I am in a different frame since the object IDE recorded is not at all in the frame. I execute  the search in all frames, the only frame that returns something is

```
browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

all other frames either return an error "frame nonexistent" or do not return the right object:

```
browser.switch_to.frame(0)
browser.switch_to.frame(1)
browser.switch_to.frame(2)
browser.switch_to.frame(3)
....
```

I really don't understand why Selenium IDE records:

```
self.driver.switch_to.frame(3)
self.driver.switch_to.frame(2)
```

I have recorded several times and it returns the same code

**Knowing the ID, is there a way to search in the whole website and retrieve the frame # it is located in?**

Comment: It is possible to write the code to check for the element in all the available frames and exit when the condition match, but I think it's not the right approach though. Instead, you can use the google chrome dev tools and console to switch between the frames and get the exact frame information.

Comment: OK, good information, thanks.